# How to get page report in omniture python

Tags: python, api, adobe-analytics

I am using omniture module in python to pull the data.

Link to module: https://github.com/debrouwere/python-omniture

Installation `pip install omniture` .

I am able to get output for key metrics. However not able to build the query for page level reports, where element & page name needs to be mentioned. And there is not enough documentation available as well.Below is the code I framed for Homepage page views its giving result but values are not correct.

```
on_kymet=reportsuite.report.over_time(metrics=['pageviews']).set({'segmentId': 'segmentname'}).set({'element': 'pagetype'}).set({'page': 'homepage'}).range(str_dt,end_dt, granularity='hour').sync()
```

Comment: Hi, Adobe Analytics API is a beast to use! I don't have experience using the Python sdk but I have written our own PHP version of this.  My first port of call on such an issue will be to examine the exact reportDescription that this library requests from Adobe, paste that here and I'll take a look.  Just to make you aware my company has developed an Adobe Analytics Connector which automates API requests (many 1000s at a time for some clients), it is very cost effective and may be of some use to you instead of starting from scratch like this?